# Unstable analog results

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a rock solid voltage on my analog input with ADC values jumping around by about 15% on the Serial monitor and LCD display
Never had anything like this before

Seeeduino V4.2
pinMode(A1, INPUT_PULLUP);
volt = analogRead(A1)

Am I the proud owner of a faulty board? ( wish I had a spare one to test )

regards
Wilfried

Comment: INPUT_PULLUP? explain. and how do you measure "rock solid"?

Comment: I think INPUT_PULLUP doesn't do anything here. Analogread does all necessary pin configuration. Have you measured the input voltage with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Probably not related but you should probably not use INPUT_PULLUP mode when you want to read an analog input. Just use INPUT mode. `INPUT_PULLUP mode internally connects the pin to +5V through a resistor, which is going to throw off your voltage readings.

Comment: I have seen this many times in the past on many different families/brands of microcontrollers.  A/D systems are extremely sensitive to electrical noise especially on the AREF pin.  Check the loading on your 5V supply, that, I believe is the source for AREF. Inductive loads are notorious for injection of electrical noise into an analog sub system. If you are powering any loads from the 5V supply eliminate them one by one and see if you get a solution. I have seen LEDs cause this problem especially with PWM.